# for loop performance in huge list or dictionary

Tags: python, performance, hypertable

I am making a research project on search engines, and i am having problems with a performance of the for loop. I have the following problem:

```
for value in hash_array.keys():  
        cell= db_conn.use_client().hql_query(db_conn.use_namespace(),'SELECT doc_text FROM SE_doc_text WHERE ROW=\"'+
                             value+"\" SCAN_AND_FILTER_ROWS LIMIT 1").cells  
        list_result[value].append(cell[0].value)
```

Using hypertable i want to have the best performance, but when i am using it on 20.000 or 30.000 elements of the hash_array.keys() i have a result like 5-6 min, so that's slow really slow. Any other way of performing a fast for? or should i use my plan b for the whole search engine.

Performance of the query:

```
  Elapsed time:  0.10 s
Avg value size:  1428.00 bytes
  Avg key size:  57.00 bytes
    Throughput:  595190.38 bytes/s
   Total cells:  1
    Throughput:  400.80 cells/s
```

Tested on hardware:

```
8gb 1600mhz
1055t amd
```

Additional facts:

```
 Without SCAN_AND_FILTER_ROWS: 1.78163504601ms
 With SCAN_AND_FILTER_ROWS: 3.27163504601ms
 Only for loop: 0.0630ms
```

With the solution (from the answer) i have the following:

```
stringRow = ' AND '.join(["ROW = \""+value + "\"" for value in hash_array.keys()])
cell = db_conn.use_client().hql_query(db_conn.use_namespace(),stringBatch+stringRow).cells  

Results:  0.355320930481ms for 2097 documents
          1.0214779377 for 3565 documents
```

It is good but it's not best solution.

Comment: are you sure it's not query overhead?

Comment: Instead of doing a separate query for each key, can you send multiple keys in batches? The overhead of each individual query may be dominating the performance here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used Hypertable but simply reading the [documentation](http://hypertable.com/documentation/reference_manual/thrift_api/) suggest the `SCAN_AND_FILTER_ROWS` clause may be a problem:

> This is an explicit optimization for the case where you're querying
>   for a very large number of row intervals (e.g. 10,000+). Instead of
>   fetching each row interval independently, this option will cause the
>   system to do a full table scan and filter the results to find the rows
>   that are desired.  Use this option with caution, it can be extremely
>   inefficient for smaller number of row intervals.

This clause may become more appropriate if you send batches of keys at once.

Reading more [documentation](http://hypertable.com/documentation/reference_manual/hql/#select) suggests batching would be possible with the following construct:

```
| '(' [row_key relop] ROW relop row_key
      (OR [row_key relop] ROW relop row_key)* ')'
```

So, construct a query with a disjunction of, say, 100 separate keys: `ROW=x OR ROW=y OR...`.

Comment: i'll post back in a second to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use SCAN_AND_FILTER_ROWS for this, it causes performance problems when you just select one row.

Some ways to make it faster:

- Create a TableScanner and add multiple rows to the ScanSpec to avoid the overhead of sending many small network messages (this is what Daniel Renshaw suggested)
- if your row keys are in a range then you can also fetch a range of row keys
- if your row keys have a common prefix then you can use the prefix search (WHERE ROW =^ "prefix")